# Cannot receive all chunk from flutter app over BLE

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, arduino-esp32

I am writing an OTA BLE firmware update between flutter Android app and an Espressif ESP32.

Basically, the flutter app sends chunks of data that the firmware expect: the chunk bears the chunkIndex so that the firmware can check nothing is missing since the last reception.

The issue I have is that not all chunks arrive to the firmware, and as it detects that issue, simply breaks the update as expected.

Note that the size of the chunk and its header is of 365 bytes (the MTU I negotiated).

As you can see — in the hope to have better comms — I introduced an extra delay which I'd like to be as short as possible (possibly 0) as I use the `withoutResponse: false`. Duration of the write is about 80msecs as per my logs.

A remark I've made is that if I use the `withoutResponse: true`, the comm is far better.

Another remark is that other BLE characteristics are actively exchanging information during the transfert process. Is that something that could create issue?

I really need something rock solid.
So what am I doing wrong?

````dart
for (int i = 0; i < chunksCount; i++) {
   final chunk = [
        OTA_RX_FB_RECEIVE_DATA_CHUNK,
        i >> 8,
        i & 0xff,
        chunkSize >> 8,
        chunkSize & 0xff
      ];
      chunk.addAll(dataChunk);
      log("OTA: whole chunk with header: ${chunk.length} bytes");

   try {
      log("OTA: writing…");
      final start = DateTime.now();
      await bleFirmwareUpdateTxCharacteristic.write(data
          //,withoutResponse: true
          );
      final d = DateTime.now().difference(start).inMilliseconds;
      log("OTA: written in ${d}msecs, now wait a bit");
      await Future.delayed(otaBleDelay);
      log("OTA: written, done waiting");
    } catch (e) {
      error("OTA: smartboxFirmwareUpdateBleWrite() error $e");
    }```
````

Comment: Is the dropped chunk random, or is there a pattern in where it happens? Without response will be faster because you are essentially writing to the platform's queue and returning. You won't be timing the actual time it takes to be received by the other device.

Comment: I see no pattern: what I can say is that it happens very quickly in the first 10 chunks. Regarding the timing I measure, it is the await time of the write with response: it is not the message round trip?

Comment: withResponse = true will wait for the round trip, but it doesn't add any resilience unless you want to resend.

Comment: Is your sender the central or peripheral in this case?

Comment: It is the peripheral.

Comment: @DanHarms Any thought Dan? I think about making a v2 protocol with handshake:  the central asks for chunks and the app simply send them over. This way the speed of transmission  will be set by the handshake itself. What do you think?

Comment: I don't believe the issue is the cadence, at least not from the mobile side. I'm not familiar with Arduino's BT stack, though, so maybe it needs something that is more controlled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244999/discussion-between-dan-harms-and-stephane-de-luca).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue in the chunk division while sending data for the OTA update of ESP32 from the Flutter app using Bluetooth Low Energy. After some research on packages, I found a related Package named: flutter_ota. I used this package in my app , and its updatefirmware function updated the ESP32 firmware over the air. Here's the link to package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ota